# Sobre escribir un input con JS

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo dos inputs, y necesito que al escribir un input se escriba en el otro pero que en el otro reciba los eventos de teclado también.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo de la siguiente manera

```js
var interval;
 document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
 
   document.getElementById("input2").value = document.getElementById("input").value;
   });
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">

<input id="input2" type="text">
```